# "Caller does not have permission" error while creating request to cloud speech api using Cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
>       at new createStatusError (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15

I am creating an Android app with Cloud function to use Cloud Speech API and Cloud Translation API. After deploying when I am trying to use that and send request to cloud it shows this error.

Any idea about this?

Comment: Have you enabled billing in your Google Cloud Platform project?

Comment: Yes, I enabled billing and also both the APIs

Comment: Did you create [a service account](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/quickstart#before_you_begin) and created a JSON key file?